# Can't login to remote debian system with RSA key and ssh.exe from Cygwin

Tags: ssh, permissions, cygwin

I need to login to a Debian server using `ssh.exe` from Cygwin. I've generated an RSA key and appended it to the `authorized_keys` file.

Debian is OK, because I was able to use the RSA key using [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to login there. However when I try to login with `ssh.exe` it says that the password is incorrect. I can't access the `./ssh/` folder from Cygwin.

Update: As I suspected, adding `-vvvv` shows the following:

```
debug1: could not open key file '/home/steve/.ssh/id_rsa': Permission denied
```

The file is there and I can view `C:\cygwin\home\steve\.ssh\id_rsa` by my file manager.

Update 2:

```
ls -lA ~/
drwx------+ 1 steve None         0 фев 27 13:20 .ssh

$ ls -l ./.ssh/
ls: невозможно открыть каталог ./.ssh/: Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The fact that you cannot access the directory `~/.ssh` is not normal. I would like to see the output of `ls -lA ~/` and of `ls -l ~/.ssh/`.

Comment: What are the permissions on that file? Please add the output of the commands that enzotib suggests.

Comment: I've added info on permissions.

Comment: Are you logged in as `steve`?

Comment: Does cygwin even have its own permissions layer? This might just be a problem with the NTFS permissions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which .ssh folder can you not access? (You won't be able to see from Cygwin it is on Ubuntu, however you should be able to see it on Ubuntu, *from Ubuntu*, if that is where it resides). If you generated the RSA key with puttygen, it will not work with Cygwin's ssh.exe because they use different formats for their key file (putty uses a file with extension .ppk which is of a different format).

You can load this ppk file in puttygen and then use `Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key` to save it in the correct format that ssh.exe can use. If you want to load that key file in Cygwin from your Windows disk drive, you can use the /cygdrive directory to get access to your C: drive (or other drive) where the key resides. You can then use -i to point ssh to it. The other alternative is to use ssh-keygen to generate a new key for Cygwin and add that to Ubuntu's authorized_keys.

Also Cygwin ssh defaults to the username you logged into windows with as the username for the remote host unless you specify it as part of ssh's command arguments.

If it still doesn't work then I'd check what ssh was doing by adding -vvv to your command arguments.

```
ssh -vvvv -i /cygdrive/c/path/to/my/id_dsa -l username host.address.here
```

(obviously replacing the correct arguments for -i -l and `host.address.here`).

Comment: I've added some debug info. I'd really appreciate if you take a look.